# The width and height of a webp image are stored in which byte

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webp

I want to get the width and height of the webp image in the gradle plugin, so I want to translate the bytes into width and height by finding the byte position where the width and height are located

nothing,I can't find the file format for webp

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container explains the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container#extended_file_format), it looks like it can be found right after the Reserved section of the header.